# Apache storm synchronized checkpoint mechanism

Tags: apache-storm

I want to know if the stateful bolt stops processing tuples when it is in the prepare and commit states, which is the synchronization mechanism.I checked the source code and felt that the bolt will enter the corresponding processing according to the received checkpoint tuple or the normal tuple. Therefore, if the checkpoint ACTION is being executed, the normal calculation is not performed, that is, the synchronization mechanism. Is it correct? ?